# How do I retrieve data from a specific Firebase field?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I cannot retrieve specific data from a field from Firebase on the press of a FloatingActionButton. I want to set the variable `varWithData` to the field `rating` from the document `Doc1` from the collection `myCollection`. I don't care about speed. How to get that field data?

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        var varWithData = Firestore.instance.collection('myCollection').document('Doc1').field('rating');
      }),
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and the data you're querying.  Your post should describe in some detail what the code is actually doing that's confusing to you.

Comment: isn't your IDE giving you an error  on ``field('rating');``  you cannot query just a field in firebase you have to query  by document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query just a field in Firebase, you have to query by document.

```
onPressed: () async {
    int varWithData;
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('myCollection')
        .document('Doc1')
        .get();
    if (snapshot != null) {
        varWithData = snapshot.data['rating'];
    }
    print(varWithData);
},
```